# Alert when someone is added as reviewer in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

### Our company is using Team Foundation Server 2015 and we want to setup a team alert, which notifies every person when this person is **belatedly** added as reviewer to a pull request. Is this possible? And if, how is it possible?

**Edit:**
Let me be more specific:
We have this branch policy, which requires the group “Project Collection
Administrators” to be included in the reviewers and to approve the code
to complete a pull request.
[image: Reviewer Rule]

---

When I create a pull request and I add the group “Project Collection
Administrators” to the reviewers, I want that every team member of this
team receives a notification. Is this possible?
[image: Reviewer Rule]

Comment: Why a person is added as a reviewer, you need to notify every person in the team?

Comment: For your update, sorry for now team alerts is not  apply to the Collection level. You can't directly notice to a collection level group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either create a Code Review Alert for a specific team member or entire team.

- First, you must configure an SMTP server to support TFS.
- Second, you must be a member of the `Project Collection
  Administrator` or `Team Foundation Administrator` groups. *If you’re
  not a member of these groups, you won't see the options available on
  `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_admin/_alerts`
  for administering alerts.*
- If you want to only send the reviewer choose the name of the team member from the drop down list, or type the name in the search box. For team, directly use **team alert**.

[image]

- Create a code review alert **A code review in this project  changes** for this team member or a team alert for entire team. Then he/everyone in the team will receive email alert when there is a review request to him/team.

Moreover, you could set more customize filters as your wish. Details take a look at this topic: [Set alerts for your team](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications#set-alerts-for-your-team)

Comment: Can we not use tfs notification events?

Comment: When I want to create an alert, there is no option **A code review in this project changes** ([Alert Options](http://imgur.com/NEYk2hE)). Is this new in TFS 2017?

Comment: @PatrickStoeckle Seems you are using GIT for source control. You need to use the alert related to pull request , it's the same thing with code review in TFVC. You could give a try with **a pull request is created or updated in this team project**